# how to add a loading spinner while a selected filter populates results?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML code for a gallery section on my website:
I'm also using bootstrap for the layout and styling, 
everything works well here, when the filter is clicked it loads and deploys results for the selected filter:

```
<!-- ### First Section Begins ### -->

<div class="section third">
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
<div class="work col-lg-12 cold-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h2>Work</h2>
</div>
<div class="filters ">
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="wp">WordPress</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="gr">Graphic Design</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="ecomm">E-Commerce</button>


</div>



<div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp" >
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon" >

    </div>


<div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px"   calss="img-respon">
    </div>

    <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter gr">
            <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px"  calss="img-respon">
        </div>

        <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter ecomm">
                <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px"  calss="img-respon">
            </div>

            <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
                    <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px"   calss="img-respon">
                </div>

                <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
                        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px"   calss="img-respon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

and this is the JavaScript code to navigate between filter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".filter-button").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        if(value == "all")
        {
            //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.filter').show('1000');
        }
        else
        {
//            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
//            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
            $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
            $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');

        }
    });

    if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
$(this).removeClass("active");
}
$(this).addClass("active");

});
```

In that example, how can I add a loading spinner while a filter is clicked and waiting for results to be deployed ? please try to be as specific as you can :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter-button").click(function() {

    document.getElementById("items").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("spinner").className = "spinner";

    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("items").className = "show";
      document.getElementById("spinner").className = "not-spinner";
      var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

      if (value == "all") {
        //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.filter').show('1000');
      } else {
        //            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
        //            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
        $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show('3000');

      }

    }, 2000); // change this value to control loading time. 2000 = 2 seconds

  });

  if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
  $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

```css
/* This controls the visibility of the spinner and items. Do not change */

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* Change spinner css from here onwards */

.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner>div {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section third">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="work col-lg-12 cold-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h2>Work</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="filters ">
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="wp">WordPress</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="gr">Graphic Design</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="ecomm">E-Commerce</button>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="spinner" class="not-spinner">
        <div class="rect1"></div>
        <div class="rect2"></div>
        <div class="rect3"></div>
        <div class="rect4"></div>
        <div class="rect5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="items" class="row">
      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">

      </div>


      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter gr">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter ecomm">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the code snippet below. Hope you are expecting something like this.

For more loading spinners, visit [SpinKit](https://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/)

I have used a `setTimeout()` function to control the loading time and the spinner.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter-button").click(function() {

    document.getElementById("items").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("spinner").className = "spinner";

    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("items").className = "show";
      document.getElementById("spinner").className = "not-spinner";
      var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

      if (value == "all") {
        //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.filter').show('1000');
      } else {
        //            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
        //            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
        $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show('3000');

      }

    }, 2000); // change this value to set the loading time
    // 2000 ms is 2 seconds

  });

  if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
  $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

```css
/**
* hide and show classes control the spinner and items visibility
So dont replace this
*/

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}


/** Replated to the spinner
  Can replace
*/

.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner>div {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ### First Section Begins ### -->

<div class="section third">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="work col-lg-12 cold-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h2>Work</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="filters ">
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="wp">WordPress</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="gr">Graphic Design</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="ecomm">E-Commerce</button>


      </div>

      <div id="spinner" class="not-spinner">
        <div class="rect1"></div>
        <div class="rect2"></div>
        <div class="rect3"></div>
        <div class="rect4"></div>
        <div class="rect5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="items" class="row">
      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">

      </div>


      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter gr">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter ecomm">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>

      <div class="work_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 filter wp">
        <img src="./Assests/images/icodetheweb.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" calss="img-respon">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st thanx for ur answer very much / I tried this and the spinner works, but the layout of my bootstrap is broken now / instead of having the gallery images list side by side they are now listed vertically / ...

Comment: Check it in your local. I have it like this https://prnt.sc/pxo3dy

Comment: right , the 1st view comes looking well / 3 top 3 bottom / then when the botton filter is clicked it goes vertical !!